# Get parent element state from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I have a component with a changing state and I want to get the value of "gender" from the parent component. How can I do that ?

```
class CardSegment extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { gender: 'male', val: true };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>
        <Segment style={styles.SegmentStyle}>
          <Button
            active={this.state.val}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ gender: 'male', val: true })}
            style={styles.SegmentBtnStyle}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Male</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button
            active={!this.state.val}
            onPress={() => this.setState({ gender: 'female', val: false })}
            style={styles.SegmentBtnStyle}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Female</Text>
          </Button>
        </Segment>
      </StyleProvider>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: pass it as a prop to the child?

Comment: Where is your child component? You can always pass it as props, as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: CardSegment is the child component and I want to get the value of gender from a Parent component.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume you have parent component that does some logic and pass the `gender` as a prop .. (stateless component)

```
const ParentComponent= props => {
  const gender= 'your parent component should handle the "gender" logic here'

  return <CardSegment gender={gender} />;
};
```

In CardSegment (the child component !!?!) Use componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle method only to update state synchronously.

```
class CardSegment extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { gender: '', val: true }; 
}
componentWillReceiveProps(props){
  this.setState({gender: this.props.gender });
}
  render() {
    return (
    <StyleProvider style={getTheme(commonColor)}>
      <Segment style={styles.SegmentStyle}>
        <Button
          active={this.state.val}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ gender: 'male', val: true })}
          style={styles.SegmentBtnStyle}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Male</Text>
        </Button>
        <Button
          active={!this.state.val}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ gender: 'female', val: false })}
          style={styles.SegmentBtnStyle}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Female</Text>
        </Button>
      </Segment>
    </StyleProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanna pass gender value from CardSegment (child) to another component which is the parent ! not the opposite

Comment: np ... ba3dek bedek mosa3ade?

Comment: Try to pass a function from parent to child , that function is `onPress`, as the parent will have the gender `state` , in the child you only need to use this function, on the parent all `onPress` logic and the gender `state`